# Naming Smart Desktop Widget in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I have created ans Ektron Smart Desktop widget in Workarea\Widget.But I couldn't change the title of that widget.How to give a title to Ektron Smart Desktop widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your Custom Smart Desktop widget inherits from the "WorkareaWidgetBaseControl" class.
You can make use of the  following function from  WorkareaWidgetBaseControl class,

```
SetTitle("Your widget Title");
```